# How to make SVG fallback to simple text

Tags: svg

I want to inline SVG code in HTML and have simple text (like "alt") as fallback for not supporting browsers. It's desired that the text could be formatted with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to toggle display of some text based on whether svg is supported or not:

```
<style>
  /* if svg is supported - hide the fallback */
  .svg .fallback { 
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<svg> ... </svg>
<div class="fallback"></div>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wfz2Lms/).

Comment: Is there a solution that does not need Java Script? it might be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreignObject element to display fallback text.

If the browser supports SVG, foreignObject element contains fallback contents will be hidden by display attribute.
If the browser does not support SVG, elements defined by SVG have no effect, so fallback div element will be shown.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        div.fallback{color:red;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"/>
            <foreignObject display="none">
                <div class="fallback">This browser does not support inline SVG.</div>
            <foreignObject>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```